# Firestore Database: How to search for an email in multiple documents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to find the ID of a document, and I must do it by comparing the email that each document contains.

This is my database:

[image]

For example, I know the email "mipaciente2@gmail.com", and I don't know what document that email is in, what query do I have to do to search each document until I find the one that contains that email?

Comment: It sounds like you'll want to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) for that. If you're having trouble making that work, I recommend editing your question to include a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to have a subcollection reference which is the `patients` and then create a query using the `where()` method to find the `email` field with a specific value. Though, I'm not sure what version you are using. I'll just give the modular and the namespaced versions. See sample snippets below:

Web Version 9 (modular):

```
import { collection, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";

// For `user's-document-id`, I guess you have it.
const patientsRef = collection(db, "users", "<user's-document-id>");

// Create a query against the collection.
const q = query(patientsRef, where("email", "==", "mipaciente2@gmail.com"));
```

Web Version 8 (namespaced):

```
var patientsRef = db.collection("users").doc("<user's-document-id>").collection("patients);

// Create a query against the collection.
var query = patientsRef.where("email", "==", "mipaciente2@gmail.com");
```

---

For more information, you may want to check out this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).